# bad czech chars in $_POST

Tags: php, email, encoding

From form on site with encoding

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

I'm sending text from using jquery

`$.post("mail.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
$('#success').html(response);
});`

In mail.php I'm using mail function and sending text to email obtained from $_POST variable, but on email I recieve bad czech characters like `Moc pÄknĂŠ webovĂŠ strĂĄnky mĂĄte` :(

Comment: Is `mail.php` giving you back UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Break the process down! Browser to PHP through Javascript to mail seen in email client is too long a chain to say anything useful about. Check at each step what the text looks like and debug where it starts to go awry.

Comment: When you are working with internationalization, every single entity through which it passes/comes in contact with needs to be UTF-8 compliant. And I mean **everything** _even your coffee cup sitting on the desk needs to be UTF-8 compliant_

Comment: @Raidenace Damn! That explains all those encoding problems... does ThinkGeek sell UTF-8 compliant mugs?